# Css hover transition not working on live links

Tags: css, wordpress, hover, transition

Basically I'm trying to use css transitions on hover of my links. The problem is that once the links are live, (meaning a href="#" is changed to a href="yahoo.com" for example) the transitions not only stop working, but instead of opening the link, it adds the link destination to the end of my homepage address like so: "driveandambition.com/yahoo.com" which of course doesn't work. What in the actual hell is going on?? I've been pulling my hair out for hours trying to pick this booger out. It makes no sense to me why its not working or why its adding the destination to the end of the address.

I've included the css and php/html code from the sidebar.php which is the main place its happening down in the social media area. I've only included sidebar.php code but the transitions don't work on any links anywhere once they are made real. When its not real, the transitions work. I hope I have followed protocol in asking questions :( Thanks for your help, you may save a life.

Site found here driveandambition.com ...its still under construction.

```
<?php
    /**
     * @package WordPress
     * @subpackage Drive and Ambition
     */
    ?>
                <div id="menu">
                    <div id="m-logo"><a href="/" title="Home"><img src="http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/dna-logo.png" width="200" height="227" alt="Drive &amp; Ambition" /></a></div>
                    <hr />
                    <div id="nav">
                        <ul id="nav-list">
                <li><a href="#" title="About">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Blog">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Shop">Shop D&amp;A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <div id="m-end">
                        <div id="social">
                            <a href="#" class="soc-left" title="D&A on Twitter" target="_blank"><span><img src="http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/twttr.png" width="18" height="16" alt="D&amp;A Twitter" />Twitter</span></a>

                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/DriveAndAmbitionVA" title="D&A on Facebook" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/fcebk.png" width="8" height="16" alt="D&amp;A Facebook" />Facebook</a>

                <a class="soc-left" href="http://vimeo.com/driveandambition" title="D&amp;A on Vimeo" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/vimeo.png" width="16" height="16" alt="D&amp;A Vimeo" />Vimeo</a>

                <a href="http://driveandambition.tumblr.com/" title="D&amp;A on Tumblr" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/tmblr.png" width="16" height="16" alt="D&amp;A Tumblr" />Tumblr</a>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="m-search"><input name="Search" type="text" id="search" value="search" size="28" maxlength="140" /></div>
                        <p id="extra">&copy;2012 DRIVE &amp; AMBITION 
                        Site:<a href="http://rawinn.tumblr.com/" target="_blank">FTWinn</a></p>
                    </div><!--end m-end-->
                </div><!--end menu-->

    /*
    Theme Name: Drive and Ambition
    Theme URI: http://www.driveandambition.com
    Description: A clean and minimal theme that is compatible with WordPress 3.0
    Author: W.A.T.T.S.
    Author URI: http://rawinn.tumblr.com
    Version: 1.0
    */

    @charset "UTF-8";

    @font-face {
            font-family: 'BigNoodleTitlingRegular';
            src: url('http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/themes/DAPG/big_noodle_titling-webfont.eot');
            src: url('http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/themes/DAPG/big_noodle_titling-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/themes/DAPG/big_noodle_titling-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/themes/DAPG/big_noodle_titling-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/themes/DAPG/big_noodle_titling-webfont.svg#BigNoodleTitlingRegular') format('svg');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;

    }

    @font-face {
            font-family: 'BigNoodleTitlingOblique';
            src: url('http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/themes/DAPG/big_noodle_titling_oblique-webfont.eot');
            src: url('http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/themes/DAPG/big_noodle_titling_oblique-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/themes/DAPG/big_noodle_titling_oblique-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/themes/DAPG/big_noodle_titling_oblique-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/themes/DAPG/big_noodle_titling_oblique-webfont.svg#BigNoodleTitlingOblique') format('svg');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;

    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'BastardusSansRegular';
        src: url('http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/themes/DAPG/bastardussans-webfont.eot');
        src: url('http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/themes/DAPG/bastardussans-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/themes/DAPG/bastardussans-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/themes/DAPG/bastardussans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/themes/DAPG/bastardussans-webfont.svg#BastardusSansRegular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;

    }

    a:link,input[type="submit"],input[type="button"] {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    a   {
        text-decoration: none;  
    }

    img {
        outline: none;  
    }

    /*html  {
        background: url(http://www.driveandambition.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/IMG_3047.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }*/

    body    {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        min-height: 100%;
        font-family: 'BastardusSansRegular', "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    }

    .clear  {
        clear: both;        
    }

    #header {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #header h1  {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #wrap {
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 35px;
    }

    #container {
        /*background-color: #F06;*/
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 650px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #menu {
        background-color: #fff;
        float: left;
        min-height: 628px;
        width: 225px;
        padding-top: 15px;
        /*padding-bottom: 25px;*/
        font-size: 13px;
        margin-right: 35px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #m-logo {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        margin-left: auto;
        width: 200px;
        min-height: 227px;  
    }

    #menu hr    {
        margin-top: 25px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-left: auto;
        width: 185px;
        border-top-width: 1px;
        border-right-style: none;
        border-bottom-style: none;
        border-left-style: none;
        border-top-color: #444;
        border-right-width: 0px;
        border-bottom-width: 0px;
        border-left-width: 0px;
        border-top-style: dashed;
    }

    #nav    {
        font-family: 'BigNoodleTitlingRegular', sans-serif;
        font-size: 32px;
        min-height: 158px;
        width: 200px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        /*background-color:#C69;*/
    }

    #nav ul {
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        margin-left: 30px;
        /*background-color: #9F9;*/
    }

    #nav-list li    {
        list-style-position: inside;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    #nav-list li a  {
        color: #555;
    }

    #nav-list li a:hover    {
        color: #000;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.7s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: color 0.7s ease-out;
    }

    #m-end  {
        width: 173px;
        min-height: 155px;
        /*background-color: #333;*/
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        font-size: 11px;
    }

    #social {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        min-width: 170px;
        font-family: 'BigNoodleTitlingRegular', sans-serif;
        line-height: 18px;
        font-size: 17px;
        /*background-color: #993;*/
        min-height: 25px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    #social a   {
        color: #000;
        display: block;
        height: 20px;
        width: 65px;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    #social a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #000;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.7s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: color 0.7s ease-out;
     }

    .soc-left   {
        margin-right: 7px;  
    }

    #m-search   {
        width: 170px;
        height: 30px;
        /*background-color: #000;*/
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    #search {
        color: #999;

        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px; 
    }

    #menu p {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;  
    }

    #extra  {
        font-size: 10px;
        width: 170px;
        line-height: 18px;
        font-family: 'BastardusSansRegular';
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    #extra a    {
        color: #555;
    }

    #extra a:hover  {
        color: #F00;
    }


    #content    {
        /*background-color:#CF0;*/
        margin-left: 260px; 
    }

    /*//////// Blog //////////*/

    .p-box  {
        background-color: #fff;
        height: 260px;
        width: 280px;
        float: left;
        padding: 25px 20px 20px 20px;
        margin: 0 15px 15px 0;

        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .details    {
        height: 20px;
    }

    .p-date {
        float:left;
        font-family: 'BigNoodleTitlingRegular', sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        color: #df1f26;
    }

    .p-spacer   {
        float:left;
        font-family: 'BigNoodleTitlingRegular', sans-serif;
        margin: 0px 5px 0px 3px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 18px;
    }

    .p-cat  {
        float:left;
        font-family: 'BigNoodleTitlingRegular', sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

    .p-cat a    {
        color: #777;    
    }

    .p-cat a:hover  {
        color: #000;    
    }

    .p-title    {
        font-family: 'BigNoodleTitlingRegular', sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

    .p-title h2 {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }

    .p-title h2 a {
        color: #000;
    }

    .p-title h2 a:hover {
        color: #777; 
    }

    .image  {
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .image  img {
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px; 
    }

    .img iframe {
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px; 
    }

    /*//////// single //////////*/

    #p-page {
        width: 760px;
        min-height: 618px;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 30px 20px 20px 20px;

        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #post p {
        line-height: 20px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

    #post a {
        color: #f00;
    }

    #post a:hover   {
        color: #777;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.7s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: color 0.7s ease-out; 
    }

    #p-meta {
        background-color: #9C0;
        width: 200px;
        height: 25px;   
    }

    #edit   {
        font-family: 'BigNoodleTitlingRegular', sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;

    }

    #edit a {
        color: #777;
    }

    #edit a:hover   {
        color: #000;

    }

    /*//////// Page //////////*/

    .p-comments {
        font-family: 'BigNoodleTitlingRegular', sans-serif;
    }

    .p-comments a   {
        color: #777;
    }

    .p-comments a:hover {
        color: #000;
    }

    #page-title {
        font-family: 'BigNoodleTitlingRegular', sans-serif; 
    }

    #page-title h1  {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0px;    
    }

    #p-bod  {
        min-height: 350px;
        width: 760px;
        background-color: #fff;
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

    #post img   {
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .image iframe   {
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px; 
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [reduced test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/) on [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/) or [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: sorry, here you go: git clone git://gist.github.com/1850800.git gist-1850800

Answer (score 0):

add http://www. to any external links other wise they are considered relative links.

To clarify,

Absolute links - links that go specifically to a web page; e.g. http://www.yahoo.com
Relative links - links that go to a page relative to the current one; e.g news.html

You are asking for the link to go to yoursite.com/yahoo.com and there is no page called yahoo.com within that folder, so it kind of barfs.

To navigate inside folders, for example if you have an index page, and then images separately filed (as you should for organizational purposes) you can link to them by using a relative link of '/images/theimage.png' You can use this to clean up all of the absolute links to files within your website's css.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Teddy. When I add the http://www, it causes the transition to stop working. Without the http://www the transition works but then the links act weird. Even using www. without the http results in the links acting crazy. I have never come across anything like this in my 5 years of simple coding.

Comment: Get as specific to that element as you can.

If it is inside of a div, inside of a span inside of a span again for example let's try to target that link by saying: div span span a:hover {text-decoration:underline;} You can also look in your debugging tools to see if that is somehow getting overwritten by another class. Also, try to add !important to your hover state, even though that is kind of hackney.

Comment: I made the css more specific but still no change. Why would the transition only work when the a href isn't live? Nothing else about the links change. This problem doesn't make sense.

Here's the change to the css I made.
`#menu #m-end #social a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #000;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.7s ease-out !important;
 -moz-transition: color 0.7s ease-out !important;
 }`

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: here's how I had the menu laid out git clone git://gist.github.com/1870356.git gist-1870356

Comment: I believe I've found the answer to my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811942/css-transition-only-working-on-some-elements